# Protractor: Check for element present while upload is in progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, webdriverjs

I am using protractor for automating AngularJS application. There is a scenarios where I need to upload an image using the browse button and check that a progress bar is present while uploading in progress.

I am using the following code to achieve the same:

```
element(locator).sendKeys(pathOfTheImage);
expect(element(locatorOfProgressBar).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

The problem here is - although the progress bar is present, the assertion fails always because `element(locator).sendKeys(pathOfTheImage);` command is still in progress and has not returned anything to proceed with the next command , which is the assertion point.

I have tried using turning off the Synchronisation with no success:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Any solution to this issue? How can I proceed with the next commands without waiting for the sendKeys command to succeed?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with catching an intermediate progress animation.

You have to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `true` (this helps not to wait for angular to settle down) and use `browser.wait()` to explicitly wait for the animation [to become visible](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

```
element(locator).sendKeys(pathOfTheImage);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(locatorOfProgressBar), 5000, "No progress animation is visible");
```

And don't forget to revert `ignoreSynchronization` back to `false` after.

Comment: In my case locatorOfProgressBar is still not located , while upload in progress. I used the technique you suggested.

Comment: @Mfsi.AbhishekSwain thanks for the update, is there a way I can reproduce your issue? (in case the site is public)